Are floats considered "landing gear"?
Considering the actual technical definitions, are floats on seaplanes considered "landing gear"?

In what context?  What "technical definition" are you referring to?  (in the context of your other question that spawned this one, consider it or not at your diescretion.)

I mean like regulators FAA, ICAO, EASA, etc definitions

Ok, but again for what context and purpose?  Required maintenance procedures on landing gear during annual and 100 hour inspections?  If they call for putting the airplane on jacks to "swing the gear" or to measure and inspect disc brake pads the obvious answer is no.  If it is a structural specification for the design strength of struts to support the weight of the aircraft, then obviously yes.  You need to specify why you are asking if you hope to get a useful response...

In the context of categorizing airplanes, like retractable and non retractable landing gear airplanes.

They are categorized as "Seaplanes".  (we don't look at a seaplane and wonder what to call the floats, we look at the floats and call it a seaplane.)

I would consider the floats on a floatplane to be landing gear.  For most floatplanes, they are removable / optional and could be replaced with fixed gear instead.
Flying boats have the fuselage as a hull of a boat -- I would have a slightly harder time considering the hull of a flying boat as landing gear.  In particular because many flying boats are actually amphibious -- where we would clearly consider the retractible wheels as landing gear.
There are also floatplanes that have amphibious floats -- floats with wheels.
When I have thought of helicopters with skids, I think of them as landing gear.  Helicopters also can have floats -- which are little more than puffy skids.

"I would consider the floats on a floatplane to be landing gear", is it an opinion or do you refer to some  framework, legal or technical, for which this choice is decisive?

"helicopters with skids" ... That is another good point
